# Django check if field is valid for prefetching

Tags: django, django-models

Given models:

```
class Parent:
  ...


class Child:
  parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  parent_id = models.IntegerField()
```

Is there a way to check that `parent` is valid for prefetch - without actually running the query and crashing?

Given a list like `['parent', 'parent_id']` I want to do something like: `Child.prefetch_related(['parent', 'parent_id'])` where it ignores `parent_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function below to return a list of prefetchable fields.

```
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase

def get_prefetchable_fields(instance):
    opts = instance._meta
    ret = []
    for field in opts.get_fields():
        if not isinstance(instance, ModelBase):
            rel_obj_descriptor = getattr(instance.__class__, field.name, None)
        else:
            rel_obj_descriptor = getattr(instance, field.name, None)
        if rel_obj_descriptor:
            if hasattr(rel_obj_descriptor, 'get_prefetch_queryset'):
                ret.append(field.name)
            else:
                rel_obj = getattr(instance, field.name)
                if hasattr(rel_obj, 'get_prefetch_queryset'):
                    ret.append(field.name)
    return ret
```

Passing in a model to the function will return a list of `ForeignKey` fields directly on the model that can be used in `prefetch_related`.

```
prefetchable = get_prefetchable_fields(Child)  # ['parent']
fields = ['parent', 'parent_id']
Child.objects.prefetch_related(*[field for field in fields if field in prefetchable])
```

As a bonus if you pass in a model instance it will also return related fields from another model.

```
instance = Parent.objects.first()
prefetchable = get_prefetchable_fields(instance)  # ['child_set']
```